# Copy all files one folder to another Folder using PHP code

Tags: php

I want to copy all files from one folder to another folder using PHP scripts. So if I have a file `demo/index.php` then I would like to copy `index.php` to `test/index.php`

Comment: Please post your code and your exact error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to recursively copy files and folders:

```
function smartCopy($source, $dest, $options=array('folderPermission'=>0755,'filePermission'=>0755))
{
    $result=false;

    if (is_file($source)) {
        if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') {
            if (!file_exists($dest)) {
                cmfcDirectory::makeAll($dest,$options['folderPermission'],true);
            }
            $__dest=$dest."/".basename($source);
        } else {
            $__dest=$dest;
        }
        $result=copy($source, $__dest);
        @chmod($__dest,$options['filePermission']);

    } elseif(is_dir($source)) {
        if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') {
            if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') {
                //Copy only contents
            } else {
                //Change parent itself and its contents
                $dest=$dest.basename($source);
                if(!file_exists($dest)) mkdir($dest);
                @chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            }
        } else {
            if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') {
                //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content
                if(!file_exists($dest)) mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']);
                @chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            } else {
                //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content
                if(!file_exists($dest)) mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']);
                @chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            }
        }

        $dirHandle=opendir($source);
        while($file=readdir($dirHandle))
        {
            if($file!="." && $file!="..")
            {
                 if(!is_dir($source."/".$file)) {
                    $__dest=$dest."/".$file;
                } else {
                    $__dest=$dest."/".$file;
                }
                //echo "$source/$file ||| $__dest<br />";
                $result=smartCopy($source."/".$file, $__dest, $options);
            }
        }
        closedir($dirHandle);

    } else {
        $result=false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then execute in this way, for files:

```
smartCopy('demo/index.php', 'test/index.php');
```

or for folders:

```
smartCopy('demo/', 'test/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to scan all the files in directory and then foreach file copy them into new directory using [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Here is the code to copy all the files, try this...

```
<?php

$dir    = 'img';
$files = scandir($dir);

///path to new directory..
$new_dir = 'img2';

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(!empty($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {
        $source = $dir.'/'.$file;
        $destination = $new_dir.'/'.$file;
        if(copy($source, $destination)) 
        {
            echo "Copied $file...\n";
        }
    }   
}

?>
```